# Plotting coordinates from tikzmath in pgfplot axis coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

## Short Version

I want to do some fairly complicated coordinate math to make a notional diagram but would like to use pgfplots since I have used it elsewhere in my document and want the axis styles (which I personally prefer) to match.

I do the coordinate math in tikzmath,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    coordinate \c;
    \c0 = (0.0,0.0);
    \c1 = (1.0,1.0);
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1]
    \draw (\c0) -- (\c1);
    \coordinate [label=$\c1$] (foo) at (0.5,0.5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but when I render this, the coordinates are not in the axis coordinate system:
[image: actual LaTeX output]

I would like instead to have the following plot:
[image: desired LaTeX output]

Is there a way to convert to the axis coordinate system from whatever coordinate system tikzmath uses?

## Long Version

I am trying to make a plot demonstrating quadratic interpolation through a few points. Specifically, I want to show how (unlike cubic interpolation) the shape of the entire curve can be wholly determined by the derivative at one point (I choose the first point). I want to draw this curve for different values of `\d0` so I figured I could make use of the cubic control points that TikZ provides (through `controls`) and [calculate what those control points should be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/336679/475643).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    % coordinates
    coordinate \p;
    \p0 = (0.0,0.0);
    \p1 = (0.2,0.6);
    \p2 = (0.6,0.9);
    \p3 = (1.0,1.0);
    % dy/dx values
    real \d;
    \d0 = 1.0;
    \d1 = 2.0 * (\py1 - \py0) / (\px1 - \px0) - \d0;
    \d2 = 2.0 * (\py2 - \py1) / (\px2 - \px1) - \d1;
    \d3 = 2.0 * (\py3 - \py2) / (\px3 - \px2) - \d2;
    % https://math.stackechange.com/a/336679/475643
    % quadratic control points
    coordinate \q;
    \q1 = ({(\px0 + \px1) / 2.0}, {\py0 + \d0 * (\px1 - \px0) / 2.0});
    \q2 = ({(\px1 + \px2) / 2.0}, {\py1 + \d1 * (\px2 - \px1) / 2.0});
    \q3 = ({(\px2 + \px3) / 2.0}, {\py2 + \d2 * (\px3 - \px2) / 2.0});
    % cubic control points, lefthand side
    coordinate \s;
    \s1 = {(2 / 3 * \q1) + (1 / 3 * \p0)};
    \s2 = {(2 / 3 * \q2) + (1 / 3 * \p1)};
    \s3 = {(2 / 3 * \q3) + (1 / 3 * \p2)};
    % cubic control points, righthand side
    coordinate \r;
    \r1 = {(2 / 3 * \q1) + (1 / 3 * \p1)};
    \r2 = {(2 / 3 * \q2) + (1 / 3 * \p2)};
    \r3 = {(2 / 3 * \q3) + (1 / 3 * \p3)};
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=60,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=60,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=\textwidth]
    % https://math.stackexchange.com/q/335226/475643
    \draw (axis cs:\p0) .. controls (axis cs:\s1) and (axis cs:\r1) .. (axis cs:\p1);
    \draw (axis cs:\p1) .. controls (axis cs:\s2) and (axis cs:\r2) .. (axis cs:\p2);
    \draw (axis cs:\p2) .. controls (axis cs:\s3) and (axis cs:\r3) .. (axis cs:\p3);
    % datapoints
    \draw (axis cs:\p0) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{0}$] {};
    \draw (axis cs:\p1) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{1}$] {};
    \draw (axis cs:\p2) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{2}$] {};
    \draw (axis cs:\p3) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{3}$] {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you ignore the bug in computing the control points (still working on it), it seems to plot everything correctly up to some scale factor:

[image: more complex actual LaTeX output]

Comment: Axis cs coordinates are only defined inside the axis environment, and tikzmath wouldn't use them anyway.  You can compute x and y values using \pgfmathsetmacro (but not \pgfmathsetlengthmacro) and use them inside the axis environment, but coordinates are always screen coordinates.

Comment: Maybe there's a better approach. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: TikZmath uses the current coordinate system, at the place it is used. In your case it uses the *xyz* coordinate system (without units) which is mapped to the canvas coordinate system (with units). Even if you move your TikZmath inside the `axis` environment, it will do weird things. At best you need to force the use of the `axis` coordinate system: `\draw[green] (axis cs: \c0) -- (axis cs: \c1);`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I've updated the post with the particular problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `\tikzmath` statement needs to be inside the `axis` environment.

  This seems to make TikZ math to interpret the coordinate specifications one-to-one, i.e. 1pt = 1.  All the following coordinate calculation will be taken out in the [canvas coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.canvas) of PGF/TikZ.
- When a coordinate like `(\s2)` is used inside a TikZ path that will result in `(0.3333pt, 1.26666pt)`, i.e. a coordinate in the aforementioned canvas coordinate system. Forcing PGF/TikZ to interpret this in the axis coordinate system by specifying `axis cs:` explicitly will turn this back to a PGFPlots coordinate (i.e. 1 = 1pt).

  Whether this is and the points before is a nice side effect of how PGFPlots axis coordinate system is implemented or a lucky accident remains to be seen. Expect this not to work properly in more complex cases (3d won't work at all, numbers greather than 16000-ish won't work either).
- The coordinate calculations for *r* and *s* are not correct:
  `\s1 = {(2 / 3 * \q1) + (1 / 3 * \p0)};` will result into

  ```
  \s1 = {(2 / 3 * \qx1, \qy1) + (1 / 3 * \px0, \py0)};
  ```

  which is probably interpreted as the addition of the two coordinates `(2 / 3 * \qx1, \qy1)` and `(1 / 3 * \px0, \py0)`, i.e. the factor 1/3 is only applied to the *x* variable.

When the `calc` library is loaded the [“normal” coordinate calculations](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.5.2) will be available:

```
  \s1 = ($2 / 3 *(\q1) + 1 / 3 *(\p0)$);
  \s2 = ($2 / 3 *(\q2) + 1 / 3 *(\p1)$);
  \s3 = ($2 / 3 *(\q3) + 1 / 3 *(\p2)$);
```

Note that there's **no** space between `*` and `(` as per the manual.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=2,
  width=\textwidth,
  height=\textwidth]
\tikzmath{
  % coordinates
  coordinate \p;
  \p0 = (0.0,0.0);
  \p1 = (0.2,0.6);
  \p2 = (0.6,0.9);
  \p3 = (1.0,1.0);
  % dy/dx values
  real \d;
  \d0 = 1.0;
  \d1 = 2.0 * (\py1 - \py0) / (\px1 - \px0) - \d0;
  \d2 = 2.0 * (\py2 - \py1) / (\px2 - \px1) - \d1;
  \d3 = 2.0 * (\py3 - \py2) / (\px3 - \px2) - \d2;
  % https://math.stackexchange.com/a/336679/475643
  % quadratic control points
  coordinate \q;
  \q1 = ({(\px0 + \px1) / 2.0}, {\py0 + \d0 * (\px1 - \px0) / 2.0});
  \q2 = ({(\px1 + \px2) / 2.0}, {\py1 + \d1 * (\px2 - \px1) / 2.0});
  \q3 = ({(\px2 + \px3) / 2.0}, {\py2 + \d2 * (\px3 - \px2) / 2.0});
  % cubic control points, lefthand side
  coordinate \s;
  \s1 = ($2 / 3 *(\q1) + 1 / 3 *(\p0)$);
  \s2 = ($2 / 3 *(\q2) + 1 / 3 *(\p1)$);
  \s3 = ($2 / 3 *(\q3) + 1 / 3 *(\p2)$);
  % cubic control points, righthand side
  coordinate \r;
  \r1 = ($2 / 3 *(\q1) + 1 / 3 *(\p1)$);
  \r2 = ($2 / 3 *(\q2) + 1 / 3 *(\p2)$);
  \r3 = ($2 / 3 *(\q3) + 1 / 3 *(\p3)$);
}
  % https://math.stackexchange.com/q/335226
  \draw (axis cs:\p0) .. controls (axis cs:\s1) and (axis cs:\r1) .. (axis cs:\p1);
  \draw (axis cs:\p1) .. controls (axis cs:\s2) and (axis cs:\r2) .. (axis cs:\p2);
  \draw (axis cs:\p2) .. controls (axis cs:\s3) and (axis cs:\r3) .. (axis cs:\p3);
  % datapoints
  \draw (axis cs:\p0) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{0}$] {};
  \draw (axis cs:\p1) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{1}$] {};
  \draw (axis cs:\p2) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{2}$] {};
  \draw (axis cs:\p3) node[circle,fill,scale=0.5,label=above:$P_{3}$] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I believe the best approach would be to not use any coordinate calculation at all but only reals.

Comment: Your fix for the `r` and `s` variables is much appreciated. This would have taken me forever to figure out on my own. I don't think that behavior (applying only to the x variable unless parenthesized) is explicitly mentioned anywhere in the TikZ manual?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, if I have the `calc` library loaded, shouldn't I be able to replace the `$...$` with `{...}`?

Comment: @segfault `\q1` is just a simple substitution (expansion) for `\qx1,\qy1`. If you use `(1/3 * \q1 * sqrt 2)` it will just be *x* = `1/3*\qx1` and *y* = `\qy1 * sqrt 2`. There's nothing recognizing `\q1` as a coordinate, it's just two length separated by a comma. The rest is just the `calc` library's syntax. First a factor, then a coordinate (with `*` beforehand) and then possibly another coordinate calculation added (e.g. again a factor and a coordinate).