# Reset tikzmath variable in for loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, tikzmath

I want to draw multiple curves (each with a different slope) using `tikzmath` coordinates:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=\textwidth]
    \tikzmath{
      % coordinates
      coordinate \p;
      \p0 = (0.0,0.0);
      for \slope in {0.5,1.0,1.5}{
        % comptue value at 1
        \p1 = (1.0, \slope);
        {\draw (axis cs:\p0) -- (axis cs:1.0,\slope);};
      };
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, it looks like only the last iteration (`\slope` = 1.5) is executed:

[image: actual LaTeX output]

I want all slopes to be plotted:

[image: expected LaTeX output]

I think this is because the value of `\p1` is not being reassigned during each iteration?

For those interested in my particular use case, I am trying to plot [multiple quadratic curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685701/195752).

Comment: Why do you use `axis`?  It is natural to draw your elements directly.  Your code will function (i.e. `\tikzmath...`) outside the `axis` environment.

Comment: Do you really need `\tikzmath`? I just wonder ... It might be easier to do without

Comment: The code I provided above is just a MWE. The full problem (which uses `axis` and `\tikzmath`)  is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685701/195752.

Answer (score 1):

Now after Edit To achieve the desired result, you can move the loop outside the `axis` environment and use the `\addplot` command within the loop to draw each curve. Here's the updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=\textwidth
]

\foreach \slope/\color in {0.5/red, 1.0/green, 1.5/blue}{
    \addplot [domain=0:1, \color] {(\slope) * x};
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this code, the `foreach` loop iterates over the values of `\slope` and `\color`, and for each iteration, the `\addplot` command is used to draw a curve with the specified slope and color. The `domain=0:1` option sets the range of x-values for the curves. By moving the loop outside the `axis` environment, each curve is drawn separately, and they are all visible in the resulting plot.

Comment: This code still only draws one line.

Comment: @segfault i edited the code , try that

Comment: It still does not work, unfortunately. It works if I move the `for` loop outside of the `axis` environment but I don't know why. I would like to use the `axis` environment if I can though since I want all the figures in my document to look the same.

Comment: @segfault try it now , i edited it .